# Squirrel.Windows - Can i classify updates according to severity, and decide whether to update/force restart based on the update's severity level?

Tags: squirrel.windows

I want to implement Squirrel's update solution in my work project,
But I wish to classify each update according to a severity (let's say, critical, feature, niceToHave etc.) and decide whether to update/force restart based on the new update's severity.

Can it be done using Squirrel?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this using Squirrel is to first design a versioning scheme that maps to severity levels. For example, consider a version format of X.Y.Z (Major.Minor.Patch). `niceToHave` increments the patch version, `feature` increments the minor version, and `critical` increments the major version.

Then you can customize [UpdateManager](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/using/update-manager.md) in your application to implement the logic that applies updates:

```
using (var mgr = new UpdateManager(pathToUpdateFolder))
{
    var updates = await mgr.CheckForUpdate();

    if (updates.ReleasesToApply.Any())
    {
        var lastVersion = updates.ReleasesToApply.OrderBy(x => x.Version).Last();

        // TODO: implement the logic to call:
        // await mgr.DownloadReleases(updates.ReleasesToApply);
        // await mgr.ApplyReleases(updates);
    }
}
```